# How to initialize reverse geocode upon page load?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I'm trying to do a reverse geocode (Google) on a place_id, following [this google dev.guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse). But instead of the 'click' event to initialize the geocode function, I want to execute the geocode function when the page is loaded. So I replaced the click-eventListener with this code:

```
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        geocodePlaceId(geocoder, map, infowindow);
        });
```

In the geocode function I've hardcoded the place_id (by means of an example):

```
function geocodePlaceId(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
        var placeId = ChIJw2IskpfGxUcRRNxZ4A_lGWk;
        geocoder.geocode({'placeId': placeId}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            etcetc
      }
```

Unfortunaltely this does not work, i.e. there's no reverse geocode initialized. Any advise to this very moderate java-programmer would be very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get javascript errors with your code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ChIJw2IskpfGxUcRRNxZ4A_lGWk is not defined`. The placeId is a string.

This:

```
var placeId = ChIJw2IskpfGxUcRRNxZ4A_lGWk;
```

Should be:

```
var placeId = "ChIJw2IskpfGxUcRRNxZ4A_lGWk";
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function geocodePlaceId(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
  var placeId = "ChIJw2IskpfGxUcRRNxZ4A_lGWk";
  geocoder.geocode({
    'placeId': placeId
  }, function(results, status) {

    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setZoom(11);
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        map: map
      });
      infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    } else {
      window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  geocodePlaceId(geocoder, map, infowindow);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```